# Efficient way to delete specific rows of a SAS dataset on a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sas, delete-row, sql-delete

I want to delete the latest 30 day records from a dataset. Then I have couple of ways to do so.

```
proc sql;
delete from server.data
where Date >= today() - 30;
quit;
```

OR

```
data server.data;
set server.data(where= (Date>= today() - 30));
run;
```

Which way is better? Or any faster procedures?

Comment: `delete` costs me almost the same time to build a new table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach is faster.

However this approach leaves the deleted observations in place (they are marked as deleted).  This causes a difference between the NOBS and NLOBS properties of the table.  So if space is a consideration,  I'd recommend the second approach (using a macro variable constant in the same manner).  This will rebuild the table without those records.  Remember to recreate any indexes and constraints, which will be destroyed in the rebuild process..

EDIT:  I had previously suggested that the below would be even faster, however this turned out **not** to be the case - see Joe's comment in the thread..

```
proc sql;
delete from server.data
where Date >= %eval(%sysfunc(today()) - 30);
```

Comment: The original table has over 10M records. That's why I don't want to rebuild the whole table. That's really time-comsuming.

Comment: Is the original table a SAS dataset?  If you are connecting to a database, try using pass through SQL..  This may be faster (although the libname engine ought to have resolved it as appropriate)

Comment: @RawFocus While your argument is interesting, you're not actually correct that today() vs %sysfunc(today()) are different.  The SAS compiler (and similar the SQL compiler when this is passed down to the database, which it likely would be even using libname SQL) are smart enough to recognize that today() is a constant.  Run a test; I just ran one using 1e8 rows (~100MM) deleting half of them, and the two ran identically.

Comment: Interesting - good to know!  Thanks @Joe!  I've edited my response.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with RawFocus, but could I also suggest to have a look at this paper? It sets out a macro that you can use to compare any two sas steps in their efficiency across a number of metrics and on your specific environment. For example, as RawFocus pointed out, if the drive is of consideration, you might want a technique which performs better on I/O and this macro lets you compare that. I am using a version of this all the time when I am asking myself which way would be the quickest/most efficient:

http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug10/ma/ma09.pdf

Regards,
Vasilij